# In Boost::Program_Options, how to set default value for wstring?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

My code below did not work:

```
wstring config_file;
// Declare a group of options that will be 
// allowed only on command line
po::options_description generic("Generic options");
generic.add_options()
    ("help,h", "produce help message")
    ("config,c", po::wvalue<wstring>(&config_file)->default_value(L"DXDrv.cfg"), "name of a file of a configuration.")
    ;
```

The compilation failed with error:

> d:\repo\a4x_ext\minidxdriver\testapp\configparser\boost\lexical_cast.hpp(1096) : error C2039: `'setg'` : is not a member of `'boost::detail::lexical_stream_limited_src<CharT,Base,Traits>'`

Comment: Which part isn't working? What did you expected to get? Now it's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: I updated my post with the error message. Could you help to show me some working example? Thanks very much for your comment!

Comment: Was there a template instantiation back-trace from the compile error?

Comment: I found some post for the auther of Program_options. The post said the default value of wstring is not supported by the library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Long-winded explanation: This is because the underlying `typed_value` type in `program_options` tries to do a lexical cast from `wchar` to `char` in setting the `m_default_value_as_text` private member. For whatever reason, the basic_string type does not have the necessary functions to create the correct template types.

Luckily, the typed_value class has a second override for default_value and implicit_value which provides a string representation of the value. This bypasses the lexical_cast, which fixes the problem. Something like:

```
     tvalue< tstring >()->default_value( _T( "output.png" ), "output.png" )
```

Comment: Why does boost program_options bother with converting the default value to a string? Who needs it?

Comment: I just realized the answer. program_options needs to show the value when printing the help message.

Comment: Excellent post! I have the same question as Syncopated. Any idea why it needs the narrow string for the default value when the output value is wvalue<std::wstring> ? Does it have to do with the help message?