# Boost.program_options: implicit_value and Unicode results in compile-time error

Tags: c++, boost, boost-program-options

I am using Boost.program_options library and need to specify implicit_value with Unicode support.

For ansi-string this code works fine

```
po::options_description desc("Usage");
desc.add_options()
    ("help,h", "produce help message")
    ("-option,o", po::value<std::string>()->implicit_value(""), "descr");
```

But if I use Unicode support like this

```
po::options_description desc("Usage");
desc.add_options()
    ("help,h", "produce help message")
    ("-option,o", po::wvalue<std::wstring>()->implicit_value(L""), "descr");
```

I get the following errors:

```
boost/lexical_cast.hpp(1096): error C2039: 'setg' : is not a member of 'boost::detail::lexical_stream_limited_src<CharT,Base,Traits>'

boost/lexical_cast.hpp(1097): error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>::basic_istream(std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *,bool)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'base *' to 'std::basic_streambuf<_Elem,_Traits> *'

boost/lexical_cast.hpp(1103): error C2678: binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type 'std::basic_istream<_Elem,_Traits>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
```

What do i do wrong?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6921196/in-boostprogram-options-how-to-set-default-value-for-wstring for an explanation and a fix.

Answer (score 1):

I get the exact same errors when trying to use the default_value method with Unicode support. However, after looking over the Boost source code, It appears that the Unicode support in program_options is incomplete (either that or the documentation necessary to use it). It seems that the use of the implicit_value and/or default_value methods really have nothing to do with the errors; rather it is the use of wvalue versus value.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an error with `boost::lexical_cast< std::string, std::wstring >`. I just created the error ticket for this [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/7929). For now you can use the overload that takes 2 parameters and provide the textual representation yourself. This also applies to the `default_value` method.